# Angular - Matierial Layout - how to set an image 50% of height of its parent (row-layout)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am in trouble with angular material layout..

Got this:

this one is just to show the whole html

```
<div id="MainLayout" layout="column" flex style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden">

  <div id="pageHeader" layout="row">
    <div layout="column" flex>
      <div layout="row" flex>
        <img ng-repeat="icon in main.social" class="social" src="{{icon.path}}"/>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" flex></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it is about this block:

```
<div id="LogoDisplay" layout="row" flex="50" ng-style="main.styles.text" style="background: #F9F9F9">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex fill>
      <div id="LogoImage" layout="row" layout-align="center center"><img src="assets/images/user-foto-logo.png" style="???"></div>
      <div id="LogoTitle" layout="row" layout-align="center end">User Name</div>
      <div id="LogoText" layout="row" layout-align="center start">Job Title</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and least I got this

```
<div id="ImageDisplay" flex="50" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <div ng-repeat="icon in main.icons">{{icon}}</div>
</div>

<div id="pageInfo" layout="row" style="background: #123; color: #FFFF88;">some info footage</div>
```

I marked the code with ???
There is my problem, got 4 rows, row #1 gots some icons and #4 is just text... 
row 2 contains a logo and two rows of text
row 3 contains a couple of logos

My Problem: I would like to  have rows 2 and 3 filling 50% of the height. the logo should take 50% of row 2 and the both texts should fit to width of the logo...

Comment: Add a codepen please

Comment: It has been made with swiip and I do not know how to post it with codepen.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what you made it. This is just some basic markup without javascript, you copy and paste it in a new codepen.